# Newbie issue with LINQ in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, exists

Here is the single line from one of my functions to test if any objects in my array have a given property with a matching value

```
Return ((From tag In DataCache.Tags Where (tag.FldTag = strtagname) Select tag).Count = 1)
```

WHERE....

`DataCache.Tags`  is an array of custom objects

`strtagname = "brazil"`

and brazil is definitely a tag name stored within one of the custom objects in the array.

However the function continually returns false.

Can someone confirm to me that the above should or should not work.

and if it wont work can someone tell me the best way to test if any of the objects in the array contain a property with a specific value.

I suppose in summary I am looking for the equivalent of a SQL EXISTS statement.

Many thanks in hope.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is currently checking whether the count is *exactly* one.

The equivalent of EXISTS in LINQ is [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.any.aspx). You want something like:

```
Return DataCache.Tags.Any(Function(tag) tag.FldTag = strtagname)
```

(Miraculously it looks like that syntax may be about right... it looks like the docs examples...)

Comment: jon skeet - how many emails do you get from fanboys on this site?

Comment: @theman: Not a lot, actually. A few mails from people I knew beforehand, but not a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks for the response.

Your code did not work.  Then I realised that I was comparing to an array value so it would be case sensitive.

However glad I asked the question, as I found a better way than mine.

Many thanks again !